# Single Firebase authentication token for multiple users

Tags: cordova, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase

Can the same Firebase custom auth token be used simultaneously to authenticate multiple (~250) instances of an app with a single uid?

If so, is this bad practice that should be avoided? I don't want to authenticate individual users, just be reasonably certain that they're accessing via my app.

Comment: Sounds like a very elaborate plan. What's your concrete question that can be answered in reasonable amount of space?

Comment: Sorry - I'll pare it down a bit! Can the same custom auth token be used simultaneously to authenticate multiple (~250) instances of an app with a single uid?

Comment: Trim your actual question please, the comments are not the place for that.

Comment: Done. (Thanks for the tips - new to SO and learning as I go.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the same Firebase custom auth token be used simultaneously to authenticate multiple (~250) instances of an app with a single uid?

Firebase Authentication tokens are bearer tokens, there is nothing that ties a specific token to a specific device or session. As such they contain all the information necessary to allow the user of that token to gain access to the Firebase data.

> If so, is this bad practice that should be avoided?

If you find a safe way to exchange the token, you may be fine. But using a single long-lived token for that many devices will be a huge pain if it ever gets intercepted as you have no way to single the individual user/account out. In the end, it is up to you to decide what will be best for you app/users.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things perfectly!